# Como manejo los certificados SSL en React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy realizando una peticion http con  **pinch** desde la libreria **react-native-pinch**, funciona con casi todas las que tienen un certificado valido, excepto una(la que esta especificada), trato de omitir el certificado y tampoco
el codigo:

```
 pinch.fetch(' https://club.zippyttech.com:8080', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control':'no-cache' },
        timeoutInterval: 10000, // timeout after 10 seconds
    //  sslPinning: { cert:'admin.clubdegolfdepanama.com'} // omit the `cert` or `certs` key, `sslPinning` can be ommited as well
    }).then((response) => {


        return response;
    }).
    catch((reason) => {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + reason.message);
        // ADD THIS THROW error
        throw reason;
    })
```

Cuando observo el codigo en modo debug desde Android Studio me arroja este error

> Error - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Puedes acceder por `http://club.zippyttech.com` sin `https`? Creo que está mal configurado su HTTPS. Si fuera eso, no es un problema de React o JavaScript.